# Llamar a una función desde otra Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

tengo una lista de puntos con coordenadas (x, y) que se distribuyen de forma circular y quiero hacer una función que ajuste una circunferencia sobre dichos puntos. Hasta ahora lo he conseguido hacer por partes utilizando dos funciones con el siguiente código:

from scipy import optimize as opt

```
    def calc_R(x, y, xc, yc):
        """ Calcula la distancia de cada punto 2D al centro de la circunferencia (xc, yc) """
        return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)

    def f_2(c, x, y):
        """ Calcula la distancia algebráica entre los puntos 2D y el círculo medio con centro en c=(xc, yc) """
        Ri = calc_R(x, y, *c)
        return Ri - Ri.mean()

    # Coordenadas del baricentro (estimación inicial del centro del círculo)
    x_m = laja.x.mean()
    y_m = laja.y.mean()
    barycenter = x_m, y_m

    # Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
    circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter, args=(laja.x, laja.y))
    xc, yc = circle_center

    # El valor del radio viene dado por la expresión:
    r = calc_R(laja.x, laja.y, *circle_center).mean
```

Me gustaría crear una única función que se llame fitting por ejemplo que llame a las dos que ya tengo, para poder utilizarla más adelante, pero no sé muy bien cómo enfocar el problema. No estoy segura de si debería tratar de hacer una función anidada o encontrar la manera de llamarlas desde "dentro". Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cualquiera de los enfoques es válido. Si crees que las funciones `calc_R` o `f_2` puedan ser útiles para otras partes del programa, deberían ser funciones independientes. Si crees que su funcionalidad es muy específica y que sólo son útiles en el contexto de la función `fit_circle`, podrian ser funciones internas (anidadas).

En tu caso ambos enfoques son posibles, porque las funciones en cuestión no dependen de variables globales, sino que se comunican sólo a través de sus parámetros y valores retornados (lo cual es una buena decisión de diseño).

Aparentemente el único parámetro que necesitaría tu función de "fitting" sería `laja`, que parece algún tipo de estructura o dataframe que contiene ya las listas de coordenadas necesarias. El valor a retornar entiendo que debería ser el centro del círculo y su radio. Puedes retornar ambas cosas en una tupla, o crear una estructura de datos para la ocasión (por ejemplo una clase `Circle` cuyos campos sean el centro y el radio, o una `namedtuple` con esa misma información).

Un ejemplo sencillo en el que retorno la tupla y dejo las funciones como anidadas sería:

```
def fit_circle(laja):

    def calc_R(x, y, xc, yc):
        """ Calcula la distancia de cada punto 2D al centro de la circunferencia (xc, yc) """
        return np.sqrt((x-xc)**2 + (y-yc)**2)

    def f_2(c, x, y):
        """ Calcula la distancia algebráica entre los puntos 2D
        y el círculo medio con centro en c=(xc, yc) """
        Ri = calc_R(x, y, *c)
        return Ri - Ri.mean()

    # Coordenadas del baricentro (estimación inicial del centro del círculo)
    x_m = laja.x.mean()
    y_m = laja.y.mean()
    barycenter = x_m, y_m

    # Aplicamos un algoritmo para aproximar el centro de la circunferencia.
    circle_center, ier = opt.leastsq(f_2, barycenter, args=(laja.x, laja.y))
    xc, yc = circle_center

    # El valor del radio viene dado por la expresión:
    r = calc_R(laja.x, laja.y, *circle_center).mean

    return (circle_center, r)
```

Ejemplo de uso:

```
centro, radio = fit_crircle(datos)
```